# Are all emoji constructed with codepoints outside BMP as in with surrogate pairs?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, java-8, utf-16

I am trying to learn more about emoji and how they are represented in Unicode. Somewhere I read that emojis are constructed with surrogate pairs, while I recently found '\u263A' which represents '☺'. I am just trying to understand if there is a specific rule with which all emojis are constructed or there can be any unicode value(inside or outside BMP) which may represent an emoji?
Also, it will be helpful if someone can point me to a JAVA API which identifies if a character represents an emoji or is part of an emoji representation(in case of surrogate pairs).

Comment: As far as I know java doesn't provide any special API to decide whether some character represents an emoji or not. You could however download the actual list of emoji character from https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/ and write the code to check this yourself.

Comment: Based on character type(Character.getType(ch)), I saw it either it returns 28(other symbol) or 19(surrogate). Maybe it can somewhat cover all emoji characters. But thanks for the link, maybe checking the entire list is only option available now.

Comment: [emoji-java on github](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java), which provides Java methods such as `isEmoji()`, `getUnicode()` and `getAll()`, might be worth a look. Coding this yourself might not be too difficult initially, but since each release of Unicode introduces new emojis you'd need to maintain that code.

Comment: Also, as an unrelated issue, your post raised two distinct issues, and it would have been better to raise them in two separate questions. (One of them would still have been closed as off-topic, but I think the other one would have survived.)

Comment: You should use `Character.getType(int codePoint)` to determine the type of a character, regardless of whether it is inside the BMP or not. See also `String.codePointAt(int index)`. The character `U+263A` you’ve mentioned did already exist before the category “Emoji” even existed. See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2600 for other examples. New Emojis are defined outside the BMP, not as a stylistic decision, but simply because there’s not much room inside the BMP left, to define these piles of new characters.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I cannot use any third-party library, so I was looking for some Java standard API. Looks like I will have to use Character.getType(int codePoint) for this. Another thing, does anyone know the significance of '\uFE0F' character? I keep finding it's occurrence in different emojis. It gives it's character type as 6(NON_SPACING_MARK).

Comment: U+FE0F is the character VARIATION SELECTOR-16, which basically requests that the previous character be rendered as an emoji if the character in question is also used in non-emoji contexts.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.

Comment: [1] @AnshumanPrakash Since you can't use third-party libraries, the list of emoji characters in Unicode 12.0 is [formally specified here](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-12.0/). [2] You can also [download the emoji data files here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/). [3] Java's `Character.getType()` won't tell you whether a given code point is emoji or not. It can tell you if it definitely is not emoji, or that it might be emoji, but that is all.